# Dockerfile - ERROR: for php Cannot start service php: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:348: starting container process caused "exec

Tags: php, docker, dockerfile

I'm quite newbie with using Docker and I'm trying to create a local development environment for running either my custom php or laravel projects.

This is my folder structure

```
root-dir
- src // this is where my php / laravel code lives
-- info.php // file having phpinfo(); just to ensure that everything has set properly
- docker // this is where all containers and config settings live
-- php etc..
- docker-compose.yml
```

This is my docker/php/Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

ENV TERM=linux

ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y curl zip unzip --no-install-recommends apt-utils ca-certificates
RUN apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends php7.2-fpm \
                       php7.2-cli \
                       php7.2-mysql \
                       php7.2-xml \
                       php7.2-curl \
                       php7.2-bcmath \
                       php7.2-bz2 \
                       php7.2-curl \
                       php7.2-zip \
                       php7.2-gd \
                       php7.2-gettext \
                       php7.2-zip \
                       php7.2-soap \
                       php7.2-odbc \
                       php7.2-json \
                       php7.2-geoip \
                       php7.2-igbinary \
                       php7.2-imagick \
                       php7.2-mbstring \
                       php7.2-msgpack \
                       php7.2-ssh2 \
                       php7.2-memcached \
                       php7.2-xdebug \
                       php7.2-intl \
                       php7.2-opcache \
                       php7.2-readline

RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
RUN apt-get clean
RUN rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/* /usr/share/doc/* ~/.composer


COPY php.ini /etc/php/$PHPVER/cli/php.ini
COPY php.ini /etc/php/$PHPVER/fpm/php.ini
COPY 20-xdebug.ini /etc/php/$PHPVER/cli/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini
COPY 20-xdebug.ini /etc/php/$PHPVER/fpm/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini
COPY php-fpm-startup /usr/bin/php
CMD /usr/bin/php

EXPOSE 9000

ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/bin/php"]
CMD ["--version"]
```

When I'm running `docker-compose up -d` I get this error

```
ERROR: for php  Cannot start service php: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:348: starting container process caused "exec: \"/usr/bin/php\": permission denied": unknown
```

This is my nginx/default.conf file

```
server {

  listen 80 default_server;
  root /var/www/html;
  index index.html index.php;

  charset utf-8;

  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
  }

  location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
  location = /robots.txt { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

  access_log off;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log error;

  sendfile off;

  client_max_body_size 100m;

  location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass php:9000;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_intercept_errors off;
    fastcgi_buffer_size 16k;
    fastcgi_buffers 4 16k;
  }

  location ~ /\.ht {
    deny all;
  }
}
```

Comment: So you have some files and an error. But where is the question? Do you want to know if you won't get that error when you switch from Docker to using VirtualBox VMs? Or whether you should switch from using nginx to Apache? Always include a proper interrogative sentence in your posts. (I.e. **not**: "Any ideas?", but something like "With what can I replace nginx to get rid of this error?")

Answer (score 0):

add user to your dockerfile which will execute the php binary for you something like:

```
....
RUN ["chmod", "+x", "/usr/bin/php"]
RUN ["chmod", "+x", "-R", "/var/log"]
EXPOSE 9000
RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash admin
USER admin
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/bin/php"]
CMD ["--version"]
```

Comment: You mean any user name would do or mine on my native os?

Comment: It will add a new user which which all the subsequent commands will be executed specifically the one in ENTRYPOINT and CMD. You may also give this new user elevated privileges by using `-g ` and ` -G ` flag as per https://linux.die.net/man/8/useradd

Comment: It didn't work I'm afraid, still getting the same error when I try to docker-compose -up -d

Comment: I have updated the answer. Please check now.  Add `RUN ["chmod", "+x", "/usr/bin/php"]`. Seems that your php binary is not have enough permission to run.

Comment: I did the changes you said, and after compose up I run `docker ps` which shows only the nginx container as active. I've run `docker logs <nginx-cont-id> and get this `2018/07/21 19:45:40 [emerg] 1#1: host not found in upstream "php" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:25
nginx: [emerg] host not found in upstream "php" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:25`

Comment: Also run `docker logs <php-cont-id>` and get `[21-Jul-2018 19:45:38] ERROR: failed to open error_log (/var/log/php7.2-fpm.log): Permission denied (13)
[21-Jul-2018 19:45:38] ERROR: failed to post process the configuration
[21-Jul-2018 19:45:38] ERROR: FPM initialization failed`

Comment: seems there is some issue accessing the log file as well. Though I won't recommend for production, but you can get over the problem for once by elevating the permission recursively for the `/var/log` directory like you did for the `/usr/bin/php`. Please have a look at the edited code.

Comment: It didn't work I'm afraid, still getting the same log errors, also when I try to access the localhost:8888/info.php I get `This site can’t be reached`

Comment: You have exposed port 9000 so ideally try accessing over `http://localhost:9000/info.php`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176491/discussion-between-lykos-and-piy26).

Answer (score 0):

RE:chat convo

However in your concern as to why the container stopped running.

If your command finishes executing the container will terminate
If your command fails and the tty dies, the container will terminate.

In other words if your command never runs or runs and completes, as in your example

`php -verson`

is the code you are trying to run
when that completes the container will terminate
If you are not catching `stdout` you will never see this execute
and the container will terminate as if nothing happened.

Comment: Not sure I've completely understand, but how do I keep the php container always active then? so when I run compose up all my containers keep running

Comment: ha yeah thats the hard part of docker containers. 
Your `entrypoint` should be a script or something.
I dont use php,  but I dont see people just running php the binary in docker
typically you start off with an nginx container
and launch nginx which will serve your php files
nginx runs in the background and therefore will stay running until it crashes or is shutdown

Comment: Could you give me an example for the `entrypoint` even not in php, so at least I know roughly what to google for in php? Also all my containers (nginx, php, mysql, etc) are launching from the docker-compose.yml when I run the `docker-compose up -d` so nginx will launch first, is that right?

Comment: do you have a web/http server running on the docker container you have for php?
i'm guessing no
Are you using nginx as the web/http server or as a proxy?
if web server, then I recommend you start off with just a NGINX docker container
and try getting your php based site working there first
`docker pull nginx:latest`
then run it
`docker run -it -p9000:9000 8888:80 nginx:latest sh`
get this working first then worry about docker compose
the docker compose file is to be used to make sure all supporting containers run together. you need to make your containers work first.

Comment: @Zee303 this is not a chat, nor a forum. This is a site for quality  questions and answers. If you can't comment yet, that is for a reason. One thing you should refrain from is include comments about that ( "I cant join the chat" and "hope this helps, its hard when i cant be directly part of the discussion") in an answer (and that is not because there are 5 grammatical errors in those two sentences).

Comment: @lykos
here  is someone also doing laravel in docker and nginx,. you will see they are having php and nginx in same container

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51473488/get-index-php-404-when-dockerize-laravel-app/51484185#51484185