# "GET /index.php" 404 when dockerize Laravel app

Tags: php, laravel, docker

I tried to have a very minimal setup, to dockerize Laravel app. Even the nginx able to forward the request to Laravel container, I'm still getting `GET /index.php" 404`

```
C:\yocto\snapweb>docker-compose logs --follow laravel
Attaching to snapweb_laravel_1
laravel_1  | [23-Jul-2018 07:10:04] NOTICE: fpm is running, pid 1
laravel_1  | [23-Jul-2018 07:10:04] NOTICE: ready to handle connections
laravel_1  | 172.18.0.3 -  23/Jul/2018:07:14:01 +0000 "GET /index.php" 404
```

When I went inside laravel container, this is how it looks like. Seem fine to me.

### Inside Laravel container

```
/var/www/html # pwd
/var/www/html
/var/www/html # ls -al
total 224
drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          4096 Jul 23 07:09 .
drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          4096 Jul 21 08:11 ..
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root           668 Jul 23 07:08 Dockerfile
drwxr-xr-x    6 root     root          4096 May  8 19:42 app
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          1686 May  8 19:42 artisan
drwxr-xr-x    3 root     root          4096 May  8 19:42 bootstrap
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root          1477 May  8 19:42 composer.json
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root        144199 Jul 23 07:03 composer.lock
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root          4096 May  8 19:42 config
drwxr-xr-x    5 root     root          4096 May  8 19:42 database
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root          1022 May  8 19:42 package.json
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root          1134 May  8 19:42 phpunit.xml
drwxr-xr-x    4 root     root          4096 May  8 19:42 public
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root          3675 May  8 19:42 readme.md
drwxr-xr-x    5 root     root          4096 May  8 19:42 resources
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root          4096 May  8 19:42 routes
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root           563 May  8 19:42 server.php
drwxr-xr-x    5 root     root          4096 May  8 19:42 storage
drwxr-xr-x    4 root     root          4096 May  8 19:42 tests
drwxr-xr-x   37 root     root          4096 Jul 23 07:03 vendor
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root           549 May  8 19:42 webpack.mix.js
/var/www/html # ls -al public
total 32
drwxr-xr-x    4 root     root          4096 May  8 19:42 .
drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          4096 Jul 23 07:09 ..
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root           593 May  8 19:42 .htaccess
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root          4096 May  8 19:42 css
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root             0 May  8 19:42 favicon.ico
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root          1823 May  8 19:42 index.php
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root          4096 May  8 19:42 js
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root            24 May  8 19:42 robots.txt
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root           914 May  8 19:42 web.config
/var/www/html #
```

May I know what's wrong with my setup? Here's my minimalist Dockerfiles

---

### laravel/Dockerfile

```
FROM php:7.2.8-fpm-alpine3.7

RUN apk update && \
    apk add git && \
    apk add unzip

RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer    

# Get laravel into a temporary folder.
RUN composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel laravel-install-tmp

# Move local host files to docker container.
COPY . /var/www/html

# Copy all laravel files, without overwrite files from host.
RUN false | cp -ai /var/www/html/laravel-install-tmp/* /var/www/html/ 2>/dev/null

# Remove temporary folder.
RUN rm -rf /var/www/html/laravel-install-tmp/

WORKDIR /var/www/html

CMD ["php-fpm", "-F"]
```

### nginx/default.conf

```
server {
    listen 443;
    ssl on;

    ssl_certificate /app/cert.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /app/key.pem;

    location / {
        try_files $uri /index.php?$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass laravel:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }   
}
```

### nginx/Dockerfile

```
FROM nginx:1.13.9-alpine

COPY . /app

RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/
```

### docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'
services:

  # Note, SSL cert (cert.pem and key.pem) is generated from cloudflare.
  nginx:
    build:
      context: ./nginx
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    restart: always
    ports:
     - "2053:443"


  laravel:
    build:
      context: ./laravel
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    restart: always
```

Comment: I am working on a similar issue with yii2 at the moment. This seems to be a nginx config issue (at least thats what was giving me 404's). While i am not an expert in nginx, one thing that you seem to be missing is a `root /var/www/html;`  in the server object. Maybe that will help.

Comment: But I had checked through `docker-compose logs --follow laravel`, the request has already reach laravel container successful (which is fastcgi_pass by nginx)

Comment: run nginx in debug mode and check the logs

Comment: is the `docker-compose.yml` complete? What networks do you run this with?

Comment: Thanks @SimasJoneliunas You are right at the first place. Missing out `root /var/www/html/public;` is the key solution to the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### PHP-FPM

I think you are missing the *php-fpm.conf* configuration file, mine looks just like a standard one with some changes:

- `error_log = /proc/self/fd/2` allows you to use `docker logs`
- `daemonize = no`
- `include=/etc/php/7.1/fpm/php-fpm.d/www.conf`

`www.conf` which I include in the bottom of `php-fpm.conf`

standard one with changes:

- `listen = 9000`

`Dockerfile`:

Obviously I copy the php-fpm.conf and www.conf (I use `php:7.1.14-fpm-jessie`)

```
... install & cleanup steps
COPY php-fpm.conf /etc/php/7.1/fpm/php-fpm.conf
COPY www.conf /etc/php/7.1/fpm/php-fpm.d/www.conf
```

the end of Dockerfile for php-fpm looks like:

```
CMD ["php-fpm", "--fpm-config", "/etc/php/7.1/fpm/php-fpm.conf"]
```

---

### NGINX

`default` which I copy in via Dockerfile:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;

    root /var/www/app/public;

    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    server_name _;

    charset utf-8;

    location = /favicon.ico { log_not_found off; access_log off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { log_not_found off; access_log off; }

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass pn-php-fpm:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }

    error_page 404 /index.php;

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

NGINX's `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM nginx

RUN  echo "daemon off;" >> /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

COPY default /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

# forward request and error logs to docker log collector
RUN ln -sf /dev/stdout /var/log/nginx/access.log \
    && ln -sf /dev/stderr /var/log/nginx/error.log

CMD ["nginx"]
```

### Docker compose part

You need to share volumes when composing; what I mean, NGINX + php-fpm must be able to read your *application's code*

```
volumes:
  - wherever/your/code/is/on/host:/var/www/app
```

> **Note**: this answer is WIP and I will edit / comment regularly in order to help OP.

Comment: May I know, for `php-fpm`, how does it know it needs to look for file in `/var/www/html/public/index.php` ?

Comment: @CheokYanCheng it's passed by the server (NGINX) see `fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;` So / That's why volume in NGINX should be mapped to exact "target" as fpm container (`/var/www/app` or whatever you decide to)

Comment: Thanks. Missing `root /var/www/html/public;` in Nginx container, is the reason which makes it broken. (Although error happens in `Laravel` container)

Comment: @CheokYanCheng In my first draft that was the first thing I was going to write down, then I just slapped NGINX config and figured that with rep 18k you will figure it out eventually while I provide you with some concrete example. Good for you and good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Here's my very minimal setup, which makes Laravel workable in Docker. Previously, it doesn't work, because it didn't include the following line in `Nginx` container. (Although error happens in `Laravel` container)

```
root /var/www/html/public;
```

### laravel/html (folder)

This folder is generated using the following command line. The command is executed in host machine.

```
docker run --rm -v $(pwd):/app -w /app composer/composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel html (Linux)
docker run --rm -v %cd%:/app -w /app composer/composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel html (Windows)
```

### laravel/Dockerfile

```
FROM php:7.2.8-fpm-alpine3.7

COPY html /var/www/html

WORKDIR /var/www/html

RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer    

RUN composer install

RUN cp .env.example .env

RUN php artisan key:generate

RUN php artisan optimize

CMD ["php-fpm", "-F"]
```

### nginx/default.conf

```
server {
    listen 443;
    ssl on;
    root /var/www/html/public;

    ssl_certificate /app/cert.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /app/key.pem;

    location / {
        try_files $uri /index.php?$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass laravel:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }   
}
```

### nginx/Dockerfile

```
FROM nginx:1.13.9-alpine

COPY . /app

RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/
```

### docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'
services:

  # Note, SSL cert (cert.pem and key.pem) is generated from cloudflare.
  nginx:
    build:
      context: ./nginx
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    restart: always
    ports:
     - "2053:443"


  laravel:
    build:
      context: ./laravel
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    restart: always
```

You can then access Laravel app using

```
https://localhost:2053/
```