# How to run laravel app inside docker container?

Tags: laravel, docker

I want to get docker container's result from local, following is what I tried.

**step1.
create php-composer image using dockerFile.**

```
FROM php:7

RUN apt-get update 
RUN apt-get install curl
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer -o composer-setup.php
RUN php composer-setup.php --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
RUN apt-get install -y git
```

**step2.
create container and execute laravel app.**

```
docker run -p 127.0.0.1:3000:8000 --name MyTest -dt php-composer to create a container
docker cp laravelApp/ d4bbb5d36312:/usr/
docker exec -it MyTest bash
cd usr/laravelApp
php artisan serve
```

After that, terminal shows success info:

```
Laravel development server started: <http://127.0.0.1:8000>
```

But when I access 127.0.0.1:3000 at browser, I get nothing.

Why is that?

Comment: you need to do `EXPOSE 3000` and `EXPOSE 80` in the docker file

Comment: you can use laradock. it has everything you need or will need, and it's tested and uses the best practices. I'm currently using it and it's working great

Comment: @Hussein Hello, I add EXPOSE 3000
EXPOSE 80 at bottom of dockerfile, but still can't work.

Comment: @FatemehMajd Yes, I use laradock too. It is great, but I try to build a docker-compose by myself, any idea to solve this problem?

Comment: ok i think you need also to add `ENTRYPOINT` at the end of the dockerfile:
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint

Comment: @Hussein Do you mean add ENTRYPOINT ['3000','80']  at the end?

Comment: no, `ENTRYPOINT` means when the container starts, it runs any command specified in ENTRYPOINT, a bash command, you can also specify a bash script to run inside the ENTRYPOINT, for example: `ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/bin/myscript.sh"] `

Comment: also try this command when you start the container: `docker run -p 3000:8000` (without the ip)

Comment: i'll summarize that in an answer

Comment: Check this (the whole thing) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51473488/get-index-php-404-when-dockerize-laravel-app/51477187#51477187

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there are some php extensions that are needed for laravel to work, so you need to install them too, this is the full dockerfile

```
FROM php:7
RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y openssl zip unzip git
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo mbstring
WORKDIR /app
COPY app /app # this copies all the app files to a folder called `app`
RUN composer install

CMD php artisan serve --host=0.0.0.0 --port=8000
EXPOSE 8000
```

then to run the container, run this command only:

```
docker run -p 3000:8000 --name MyTest
```

then go to `http://localhost:3000`

let me know if it didn't work

Comment: Thanks man, it works!
I think CMD php artisan serve --host=0.0.0.0 --port=8000 may be the point that solve this problem.

Comment: you are welcome, and yes and it's the same as `ENTRYPOINT`